# DRF API endpoint getting "Authentication credentials were not provided"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I am building some API endpoints with DRF. Here is code snippet.

```
class ReportsDashboardView(views.APIView):
 permission_classes = (
        IsAuthenticated, IsActiveUser,
 )

 def get(self, request, format=None):
  ...
```

I tried to call API via postman basic authentication. But it always returns "Authentication credentials were not provided."
Here is code snippet for Authentication configuration.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'] = (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
)
```

I am not sure why basic authentication (username, password) is not working for me.
Is this something you faced before? Would you like to help me?

Comment: Can you show how `IsActiveUser` is defined?

Comment: Yes. Of course. I'd defined it.

Comment: You'll need to show the code for `IsActiveUser` permission class as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the credentials you use are correct and the user is allowed access under both of the permission classes

From the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#how-permissions-are-determined) (emphasis mine)

> If **any** permission check fails an exceptions.PermissionDenied or
>   exceptions.NotAuthenticated exception will be raised, and the main
>   body of the view will not run.